# soy nuevo en java quisiera saber como obtengo los 3 valores mas grandes de un HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

compañeros buen dia quisiera saber como puedo obtener los 3 numeros mas grandes de este HashMap;
código  nombre  precio  inventario
1   Manzanas    9000.0  65
2   Limones 2300.0  15
3   Peras   2500.0  38
4   Arandanos   9300.0  55
5   Tomates 2100.0  42
6   Fresas  4100.0  33
7   Helado  4500.0  41
8   Galletas    500.0   833
9   Chocolates  3500.0  806
10  Jamon   17000.0 10

este es mi codigo la verdad soy nuevo y no sabria como resolver este problema,

```
`    class BaseDatosProductos {

    private HashMap<Integer, Productos> listaProductos = new HashMap<Integer, Productos>();

    //constructor
    public BaseDatosProductos() {
    Productos objetoManzanas = new Productos(1, "Manzanas", 9000.0, 65);
    Productos objetoLimones = new Productos(2, "Limones", 2300.0, 15);
    Productos objetoPeras = new Productos(3, "Peras", 2500.0, 38);
    Productos objetoArandanos = new Productos(4, "Arandanos", 9300.0, 55);
    Productos objetoTomates = new Productos(5, "Tomates", 2100.0, 42);
    Productos objetoFresas = new Productos(6, "Fresas", 4100.0, 33);
    Productos objetoHelado = new Productos(7, "Helado", 4500.0, 41);
    Productos objetoGalletas = new Productos(8, "Galletas", 500.0, 833);
    Productos objetoChocolates = new Productos(9, "Chocolates", 3500.0, 806);
    Productos objetoJamon = new Productos(10, "Jamon", 17000.0, 10);

    this.listaProductos.put(1, objetoManzanas);
    this.listaProductos.put(2, objetoLimones);
    this.listaProductos.put(3, objetoPeras);
    this.listaProductos.put(4, objetoArandanos);
    this.listaProductos.put(5, objetoTomates);
    this.listaProductos.put(6, objetoFresas);
    this.listaProductos.put(7, objetoHelado);
    this.listaProductos.put(8, objetoGalletas);
    this.listaProductos.put(9, objetoChocolates);
    this.listaProductos.put(10, objetoJamon); 

// y esta es mi forma de mostrarlo 
 //generate objet generarInforme
    public void generarInforme() {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
    System.out.printf(obtenerMayor()
     + " " + obtenerMenor()
     + " " + df.format (Promedio())
     + " " + df.format (obtenerInventario()));`
```

no se si me puedan colaborar se como sacar el mayor y el menor pero no se como sacar 3 grandes al mismo tiempo
Gracias

Comment: Una forma sería ordenar tu Hashmap con un algoritmo de ordenamiento y tomar los 3 valores de arriba.

Comment: 3 numeros màs grandes de precio? puedes agregar tu objeto Productos por favor?